# Does Spring expects all the beans when starting the web application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring web application. The bean I showed below is not required by the web application. So I mentioned the condition not to load on web application.
Also I am not scanning the package where this bean is defined in my ApplicationConfig.java. But I am still getting the exception

```
 Could not autowire field: private com.Foo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.Foo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

@Bean
@ConditionalOnNotWebApplication
@ConditionalOnProperty(name=LNACALL, havingValue = "true")
public Foo createFoo() {
     return new Foo();
}
```

Comment: Seems to be `Foo` injected to another bean. But according to condition, Spring didn't load `Foo`, and therefore can't find it for injection.

Comment: Yes Foo is autowired in different bean. But that bean is not scanned as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might have an @Autowired annotation somewhere else in your application that expects a bean of that type. You can try doing one of the following:

- @Autowired(required=false) with field injection to indicate that it is optional

  ```
  @Autowired(required=false) private Foo foo;
  ```
- Use setter injection instead by putting the @Autowired on a setter:

  ```
  @Autowired(required=false)
  public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
       this.foo = foo;
  }
  ```

To sum up, constructor based dependency injection (@Autowired on the constructor) is for mandatory dependencies. The required flag in @Autowired will be ignored and the bean must be present.

Setter based and field injection can be used for optional dependencies if the @Autowired required flag is set to false. If the required flag is set to false, then Spring will inject the bean if it is present. If it is not present, then the the value will be null.

Comment: Yes I have autowired Foo in different bean..But the class where I am autowiring Foo is not scanned in my Component scan..but still it is expecting the bean. Is Spring expects all the Autowired beans irrespective of the scan?

Comment: No, if your other component is not scanned, then Spring will not require Foo to be present. If you try and remove that @Autowired annotation in the other class, are you still getting the issue? Are you perhaps using Spring Boot which depending on how it's configured will automatically add your packages to be scanned? Could it be that something else is adding your packages to be scanned or you are returning that class as a @Bean? Note that sub packages are also scanned for packages specified for scanning.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how do I give @Autowired(required=false).
If I have a class where "class Boo { Autowired(required=false) Foo foo;"
Spring will not Autowire the bean if it is not available and it will not thriow error? Is my understanding right? And it will autowire if the bean is available?

Comment: That is correct, I have updated the answer to make it a bit clearer.